# Should I do main async if I need to await connection?

Tags: postgresql, dart

I am learning Dart. I need to complete query to DB with [PG driver](https://pub.dev/packages/postgres). But before I need to await for connection to make it's ready to work. I did not find better way to mark `main` as `async`.

```
main() async {
  Database db = Database();
  await db.connect();
  db.checkIfRowExists();
```

Is it's good? Or there is better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your `main` method `async` is fine if you want to use `await` inside it.

It means that `main` will return a future, and nobody will wait for that future. That too is fine. If `main` throws, the error will be reported in that unawaited future and become an uncaught error. That's really no different from a non-`async` `main` function which throws directly.

Just do it.